# Elasticsearch - When I start my Metricbeat with Docker on Mac, there is no new index created

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, indexing, metricbeat

I follow [this guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/6.8/ilm.html) to change *metricbeat.yml* as below in order to let Elasticsearch creating new index per day, e.g. *metricbeat-7.5.0-2020.02.02-000001* .

```
#-------------------------- Elasticsearch output ------------------------------
output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
  ilm.enabled: true
  ilm.pattern: "{now/M{yyyy.MM}}-000001"
```

Below is the console output:

> [index-management]    idxmgmt/std.go:182  Set output.elasticsearch.index to 'metricbeat-7.5.0' as ILM is enabled.
>   elasticsearch/client.go:171   Elasticsearch url: https://YYY.azure.elastic-cloud.com:443
>   [publisher]   pipeline/module.go:97   Beat name: XXX.local
>   instance/beat.go:429  metricbeat start running.
>   [monitoring]  log/log.go:118  Starting metrics logging every 30s
>   cfgfile/reload.go:171 Config reloader started
>   cfgfile/reload.go:226 Loading of config files completed.
>   add_cloud_metadata/add_cloud_metadata.go:89   add_cloud_metadata: hosting provider type not detected.
>   pipeline/output.go:95 Connecting to backoff(elasticsearch(https://YYY.azure.elastic-cloud.com:443))
>   elasticsearch/client.go:753   Attempting to connect to Elasticsearch version 7.5.0
>   [index-management]    idxmgmt/std.go:256  Auto ILM enable success.
>   [index-management.ilm]    ilm/std.go:138  do not generate ilm policy: exists=true, overwrite=false
>   [index-management]    idxmgmt/std.go:269  ILM policy successfully loaded.
>   [index-management]    idxmgmt/std.go:408  Set setup.template.name to '{metricbeat-7.5.0 {now/d}-000001}' as ILM is enabled.
>   [index-management]    idxmgmt/std.go:413  Set setup.template.pattern to 'metricbeat-7.5.0-*' as ILM is enabled.
>   [index-management]    idxmgmt/std.go:447  Set settings.index.lifecycle.rollover_alias in template to {metricbeat-7.5.0 {now/d}-000001} as ILM is enabled.
>   [index-management]    idxmgmt/std.go:451  Set settings.index.lifecycle.name in template to {metricbeat-7.5.0 {"policy":{"phases":{"hot":{"actions":{"rollover":{"max_age":"30d","max_size":"50gb"}}}}}}} as ILM is enabled.
>   template/load.go:89   Template metricbeat-7.5.0 already exists and will not be overwritten.
>   [index-management]    idxmgmt/std.go:293  Loaded index template.
>   [index-management]    idxmgmt/std.go:304  Write alias successfully generated.

Answer (score 1):

How did you configure the docker container network? My guess would be that `localhost` to the container running metricbeat is not the same `localhost` that you have elasticsearch listening in. Try replacing `localhost` in your metricbeat.yml with `host.docker.internal`

This post should help you:

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds